# Return promise skipping Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in a class like this that returns a promise for deleting an item:

```
function Delete(){
    // if(this.id == ""){
    //   return ?;
    // }
    return $.ajax({
       ... ajax details ...
    });
}
```

My question is, what do I return in order to 'skip' the ajax section which will validate to done so that I can do something like this (in another script):

```
$.when(Delete()).done(function(){
  ... code to execute after item is deleted ...
});
```

Comment: jQuery treats non-promises provided to `$.when` as resolved values

Comment: what @Taplar said. Try not returning `$.ajax()`, and just do `return true` after

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/  "If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when() and it is not a Deferred or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these seem work.

```
return $.when();
return true;
```

Thanks to the comments.